# Is there a list of file/image field subtokens?

Tags: 7, tokens, media, files

Token browser does not show the options for file properties. [node:file-field:0:file:url] gets the url, but is there a list of all file options? Or is there a way to check it from sourcecode somehow?

Gathering the list:

- [node:field-image:0:file:url]
- [node:field-image:0:file:extension]
- [node:field-image:0:file:name]
- [node:field-image:0:file:size]
- [node:field-image:0:file:mime]
- The last thing that is still unknown to me is if there is an option to pull image width and height? If I remember correctly that data is in the db.

Comment: Though I would add some context. I am using tokens in metatag module.

Comment: You can create your own custom tokens like [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/1143842). There is also a [module](https://www.drupal.org/project/token_custom) for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Using contrib module

[Imagecache Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagecache_token) provides a list of token for image styles, which includes image width and height.

[image: Token list provided by Imagecache Token]

If you want to have those data of original image, you can create an image style `original` without adding any effect at `admin/config/media/image-styles/edit/original`

[image: Create empty image style]

Now you can retrieve the image width and height with:

- `[node:field_image:original:width]`
- `[node:field_image:original:height]`

[image: New token list provided by Imagecache Token]

> **Downside**
>
> All images will be duplicated to the `original` image style folder.

Comment: It would be perfect if you could get the image data without the duplicate. But I guess this is a legit option.

Comment: @ram4nd Thanks, I think it would be the only way to do that without custom module. Do you feel comfortable on creating custom module? This module is the good starting point. I will look into it today later.

Answer (score 2):

For file https://www.drupal.org/node/390482#token-file
https://www.drupal.org/project/imagefield_tokens
and 
add https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_paths   add this module 
for {The File (Field) Paths module extends the default functionality of Drupal's core File module, Image module and many other File upload modules, by adding the ability to use entity based tokens in destination paths and file names.}

Check this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: The last thing that is still unknown to me is if there is an option to pull image width and height? If I remember correctly that data is in the db.

Comment: The question was not about using tokens in field settings. It was about using image field tokens in general.